# Can I edit the background in a PrimeNG p-dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng

In my Ng Application with PrimeNG library I have the following tag

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="comboLine" [(ngModel)]="selectedComboLine" optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

Is absolutely impossible for me change the background of the combo because none of the founded solution searching in Google and here works. I tried all ways but:

1. Many solutions I found requires disabling encapsulation (wrong way and in every case impossible for me because if I do this I read many error message).
2. Many other solutions referred to an old CSS selector that has been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try the following solution:

In your component.scss or component.css file :

```
:host::ng-deep .ui-dropdown-panel .ui-dropdown-items .ui-dropdown-item,
body .ui-dropdown-panel .ui-dropdown-items .ui-dropdown-item-group {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

And the output you will get:

[image]

If you want to change the input text background color

```
:host::ng-deep .ui-inputtext {
    background: lightskyblue; //change color here 
}
```

[image]

If it is hard to use viewEncapsulation then `:host::ng-deep` will allow you to override the styles.

Hope it helps